# JavasScript — Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognised expression: [href=#contact] (WordPress)

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, menu, interaction

I am trying to implement an interaction where a class is added to a specific menu item when a  is in view. Unfortunately, I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognised expression: [href=#contact]
```

Thank you in advance.

Pseudo-code

- Scroll the page
- When the section is in view add a class to the respective nav item

JavaScript

```
// Cache selectors
var lastId,
    topMenu = $('#top-menu'),
    topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight() + 1,
    // All list items
    menuItems = topMenu.find('a'),
    // Anchors corresponding to menu items
    scrollItems = menuItems.map(function() {
        var item = $($(this).attr('href'))
        if (item.length) {
            return item
        }
    })

// Bind click handler to menu items
// so we can get a fancy scroll animation
menuItems.click(function(e) {
    var href = $(this).attr('href'),
        offsetTop = href === '#' ? 0 : $(href).offset().top - topMenuHeight + 1
    $('html, body').stop().animate(
        {
            scrollTop: offsetTop,
        },
        850,
    )
    e.preventDefault()
})

// Bind to scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
    // Get container scroll position
    var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop() + topMenuHeight

    // Get id of current scroll item
    var cur = scrollItems.map(function() {
        if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop) return this
    })
    // Get the id of the current element
    cur = cur[cur.length - 1]
    var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : ''

    console.log('Cur', cur, 'ID', id)

    if (lastId !== id) {
        lastId = id
        // Set/remove active class
        menuItems.parent().removeClass('active').end().filter('[href=#' + id + ']').parent().addClass('active')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery is pretty picky when it comes to quotes in attribute selectors. You must us a quoted string for the value (either single or double).

**Change:**

```
filter('[href=#' + id + ']')
```

**To:**

```
filter('[href="#' + id + '"]')
```

If you wanted to be slightly less precise but have the benefit of dropping the `#` you could use `~=` instead of just `=` too.

Comment: Randy Casbum thank you for your help. Your solution has solved the problem.